# Can someone explain why this is throwing a stackoverflow error? (Scala, lazylist, nth prime number)

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, primes, lazylist

The Scala snippet below finds the nth prime number up to the 6500th (indexed from 0) on my machine. Calling it with `primes(6500)` returns 65071. After this (say, primes(6501)), it throws a stackoverflowerror. Any suggestions for improving it? Newbie to Scala, trying to teach myself the language - probably doing some awful stuff.

```
def primes: LazyList[Int] = { 
  def sieve(xs: LazyList[Int]): LazyList[Int] = {
    val p = xs.head
    p #:: sieve(xs.tail.filter(_ % p != 0))
  }
  sieve(LazyList.from(2))
}
```

I do not know where I can go from here...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Scala support tail recursion optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677419/does-scala-support-tail-recursion-optimization)

Comment: Scala 2.13 has problems with this but it appears to work in Scala 3 so likely to be an optimisation issue. If you are a newbie then it is probably best to start with Scala 3 if possible.

Comment: @GastónSchabas potentially - I need to rethink some things after reading that questions and the comments/answers.

Comment: @Tim I compiled it with Scala 3.3.1. You are right, I need to optimise it.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it on 3.3.3 LTS [on scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ao4PcVnoQymJUxYbCXVGFQ) and it runs OK (`primes(70000)` => `70663`). But when trying different versions it sometimes fails, so clearly very sensitive to the compiler and runtime.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it doesn't overflow in certain versions. The recursive call to `sieve` is not in tail position (`#::` is the last method called), so I would not expect the compiler to be able to optimize it away in any case.

Comment: Maybe the difference is in standard library version and whether or not some change - which doesn't affect compatibility - changes how much space one recursion takes on stack?